# Can you say "harassments", or is it always non-plural: harassment?

Tags: single-word-requests

The word "harassments" is claimed to be a typo in all my "spellchecking" dictionaries. Or maybe they all use the same "engine".

Either way, I've long been frustrated by this, as it wants to "correct" it to "harassment". It makes me wonder if "harassments" really is wrong, even though I believe I've successfully looked it up on some dictionary as existing.

Comment: Wiktionary is often among the first free online dictionaries to acknowledge count usages. But 'harrassments' might be seen as an error by some; it's as well to judge your audience.

Comment: _Harrassment_ can be a mass noun referring to an ongoing state of being harrassed, which would be only singular; or it can be a count noun, referring to individual instances of harrassment, in which case it could be plural.

Comment: *"or is it always non-plural: harassment?"* - The lack of an "s" is not what makes a word non-plural.

Comment: Whether you should use the plural or non-count form depends on the instance.

Answer (score -1):

You can use "harassments" when talking about several different accounts, but generally one uses harassment especially when talking about it in general. I hope this makes sense.